Visualizing Bubble Sort - JavaFX
Beginner here. I tried to recreate the bubble sort animation on  VisuAlgo using javaFX, but I can't get the code right:
public class BubbleSortController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Pane pane;
    private final int[] array = {10,9,11,15};

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
     
     drawRectangle();
     sortRectangles();
    }

    public void drawRectangle(){
        double startX = 60;
        double startY = 350; // Initial Baseline of rectangles
        double heightMultiplier = 10;
        double width = 35;

        for(int value : array ){
            double actualStartY = startY - (value * heightMultiplier);
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(startX, actualStartY, width, value*heightMultiplier);
            rectangle.setFill(Color.TURQUOISE);
            pane.getChildren().add(rectangle);

            startX += width + 7.5;

        }
    }


    public void sortRectangles(){
        ObservableList<Node> rectangleList = pane.getChildren();
        for(int i = 0; i < rectangleList.size() - 1 ; i++ ){
            Node nodeI = rectangleList.get(i);
            Node nodeJ = rectangleList.get(i+1);
            Rectangle rectangleI = (Rectangle) nodeI;
            Rectangle rectangleJ = (Rectangle) nodeJ;
            if (rectangleI.getHeight() > rectangleJ.getHeight()){
                TranslateTransition transition1 = new TranslateTransition();
                TranslateTransition transition2 = new TranslateTransition();

                transition1.setDuration(Duration.seconds(1));
                transition2.setDuration(Duration.seconds(1));

                transition1.setNode(rectangleI);
                transition2.setNode(rectangleJ);

                rectangleI.setFill(Color.RED);
                rectangleJ.setFill(Color.RED);
                transition1.setByX(rectangleJ.getX() - rectangleI.getX());
                transition2.setByX(rectangleI.getX() - rectangleJ.getX());

                transition1.play();
                transition2.play();

            }
        }


    }
}

I created rectangles from an array, with the numbers corresponding to the heights. Then tried to  to use TranslateTransition to sort the rectangles using their heights. I want the end product to look like the bubble sort animation in VisuAlgo.

This related example illustrates using a Timeline.

Learn to use markdown to format your posts.
